# DynamoDB Query with partition key and sort key giving me Query condition missed key schema element error

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm using boto3 in Python to make queries to a DynamoDB. I'm using a Local Secondary Index to query my results sorting by an attribute (start_date). However, when connecting two Key( ) elements with &, it gives me an error, even though the first Key() is based on the partition key.

I want to retrieve all values with PK `ra` that the Sort Key (LSI) is greater than `start`

```
def get_associated_actions_by_ra(self, ra: str, amount: int, start: Optional[int] = None, end: Optional[int] = None, exclusive_start_key: Optional[str] = None) -> List[AssociatedAction]:
        '''
        Retrieves all associated actions of a member, filtered by an optional time range specified by start and end parameters. The method allows for pagination using the exclusive_start_key parameter to determine the starting point of the action list, and the amount parameter to determine the maximum number of actions to be retrieved.
        If no actions are found, returns []
        '''
        query_string = Key(self.dynamo.partition_key).eq(self.associated_action_partition_key_format(member_ra=ra))

        if start:
            query_string = query_string & Key(self.dynamo.sort_key).gte(self.associated_action_lsi1_sort_key_format(start_date=start))
            
        resp = self.dynamo.query(IndexName="LSI1", key_condition_expression=query_string, Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES')
        associated_actions = []
        for item in resp.get("Items"):
            if item.get("entity") == "associated_action":
                associated_actions.append(AssociatedActionDynamoDTO.from_dynamo(item).to_entity())
        
        return associated_actions
```

I tried to change the query string, use it directly inside the query method and didn't get it to work.

Edit: As requested, here is my create_table:

```
dynamo_client.create_table(
            TableName=table_name,
            KeySchema=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'PK',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'SK',
                    'KeyType': 'RANGE'
                }
            ],
            LocalSecondaryIndexes=[
                {
                    'IndexName': 'LSI1',
                    'KeySchema': [
                        {
                            'KeyType': 'HASH',
                            'AttributeName': 'PK'
                        },
                        {
                            'KeyType': 'RANGE',
                            'AttributeName': 'start_date'
                        }
                    ],
                    'Projection': {
                        'ProjectionType': 'ALL',
                    }
                }
            ],
            GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
                {
                    'IndexName': 'GSI1',
                    'KeySchema': [
                        {
                            'KeyType': 'HASH',
                            'AttributeName': 'GSI1-PK'
                        },
                        {
                            'KeyType': 'RANGE',
                            'AttributeName': 'GSI1-SK'
                        }
                    ],
                    'Projection': {
                        'ProjectionType': 'ALL',
                    }
                }
                ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'PK',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'SK',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'start_date',
                    'AttributeType': 'N'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'GSI1-PK',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'GSI1-SK',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                }
            ],
            BillingMode='PAY_PER_REQUEST',

        )
```

I don't understand exactly what is "printing out the query string", so I debugged the code and got what value the query string holds at the moment of the query.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S3d3.png

Comment: Please share more of your code including how you create you DynamoDB client. Also share the output of DescribeTable

Comment: One last thing, can you print out your query string so I can see what the variables hold?

Answer (score 0):

If I was to make an assumption before you provide the requested information I would say this value for LSI sort key is wrong based on your variable naming:

```
Key(self.dynamo.sort_key)
```

As your sort key differs for your base table and index, I'm guessing you overlooked changing it to match your LSI sort key which is `start_date`

---

Your print out of the query string isn't resolved to the string and doesn't help me help you. Without seeing your entire code which you haven't shared it's hard to help you. My suggestion is to try the query with hard coded values like below:

```
def get_associated_actions_by_ra(self, ra: str, amount: int, start: Optional[int] = None, end: Optional[int] = None, exclusive_start_key: Optional[str] = None) -> List[AssociatedAction]:
        '''
        Retrieves all associated actions of a member, filtered by an optional time range specified by start and end parameters. The method allows for pagination using the exclusive_start_key parameter to determine the starting point of the action list, and the amount parameter to determine the maximum number of actions to be retrieved.
        If no actions are found, returns []
        '''
        query_string = Key('PK').eq('HA')

        if start:
            query_string = query_string & Key('start_date').gte(123456))
            
        resp = self.dynamo.query(IndexName="LSI1", key_condition_expression=query_string, Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES')
        associated_actions = []
        for item in resp.get("Items"):
            if item.get("entity") == "associated_action":
                associated_actions.append(AssociatedActionDynamoDTO.from_dynamo(item).to_entity())
        
        return associated_actions
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, as I use the default sort key when trying to query with NoSQL Workbench. I updated the question with the query string value. I also updated the code block to feature the whole method.

Comment: Updated. Please also provide more info than what you have or else it's just a guessing game for me.

Comment: Hardcoding it worked! I think the issue was that the self.dynamo.sort_key was pulling "SK" instead of "start_date". Thanks for the help! I will update here if I stumble into any more issues.